# override any event of user control when window unloads in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, wpf-controls

I have a user control and this control is drag-dropped on a window. When this window gets closed, the user control's "Unloaded" event gets fired. I want to override this event in user control (or any other event which gets fired on window close) as i want to write some logic in it before it calls the base.Unloaded event.

The problem is there is no override for "Unloaded" event like "OnUnloaded" in user control.

Is there any other event other than "Unloaded" which gets fired when window closes and that can be overriden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the below links can help

[WPF Window.Close() not triggering UserControl.Unloaded event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1499477/217880)

[Disposing WPF User Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/502761/217880)

http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2008/06/23/dispose-of-a-wpf-usercontrol-ish.aspx