# How to detect when the visual tree is destroyed?

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF application I have, I have a control that is central to the application. This control, called `ArtView`, is visible for the entire lifetime of the main window. It performs hardware accelerated rendering, and in order to avoid bogging down the UI thread, I set up an event loop in the `OnLoaded` handler for this control. Events such as mouse clicks, keyboard input, and scrolling are added to a queue that is then consumed by the event loop, but the problem I have is that I do not know how to end the event loop when the window is closed. When I close the window that contains the control, `OnUnloaded` does not fire, so what is the best way to disable the event loop when the control is no longer visible?

I am aware that I can do something like `Window.GetWindow(this).Closing += OnWindowClosing;` but that feels like a hack.

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499477/wpf-window-close-not-triggering-usercontrol-unloaded-event and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502761/disposing-wpf-user-controls

Comment: You think it "feels like a hack" to use a WindowClosing event handler to execute code when the window closes? Well, I don't want to invalidate your feelings.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I understand his argument to he honest. I'd want my controls to clean up after themselves too instead of doing that in the parent container.

Comment: Just tried a simple `IDisposable` implementation, but that doesn't seem to work either without some manual work from outside :(

Comment: Subscribe to the control's `IsVisibleChanged` event. Since your control is always visible, this event will fire only two times: on window shown and on window closed. This looks like another hack though.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I wouldn't call that "in the parent container" -- it's just an event; the window doesn't know what the handler's doing. I'd prefer to use the control's own "end of lifecycle" event if it had one, but this *is* the control cleaning up after itself. At least, it is if I'm correct in assuming that the code `Window.GetWindow(this).Closing += OnWindowClosing;` belongs to the control.

Answer (score 0):

dymanoid's solution of subscribing to `IsVisibleChanged` works flawlessly, and provides a more satisfying solution than depending on the `Window` for the cleanup of my control.

Comment: Your original approach was better. But it’s your life.