# Will the WPF user Control be Disposed if used inside a Windows Form that will be disposed?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls, dispose

So I just [learned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215(v=vs.110).aspx) that we can put a WPF `UserControl` to a windows `Form` using `ElementHost` control. If that windows form control was disposed, will the WPF user control be disposed too?

Comment: It is same. All object oriented programming language same. WPF usercontrol disposable.

Comment: @ebattulga WPF UserControl is not `IDisposable` by default and will not `Dispose`. Take a look at this post: [Proper cleanup of WPF user controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550212/proper-cleanup-of-wpf-user-controls). The `Dispose` method of the `ElementHost` control checks if the `Child` is `IDisposable` then calls its `Dispose` method. So if you need to `Dispose` anything, you should implement `IDisposable` interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your WPF `UserControl` is `IDisposable` the answer is yes, otherwise no.

In the source code for `Dispose` method of [`ElementHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) class which hosts a WPF `UserControl`, you can see this:

```
IDisposable child = this.Child as IDisposable;
if (child != null)
{
    child.Dispose();
}
```

Which means the `Child` will be disposed, if it's `IDisposable`.

**Note**

WPF doesn't rely on `IDisposable` interface for resource cleanup. But since the `UserControl` will be used in a Windows Forms Project in an `ElementHost` control which supports `IDisposable` pattern, you can rely on `IDisposable` pattern if you need to perform some resource clean up. But if it was a WPF project, you should use WPF mechanisms for resource clean up.