# Would references in XAML causes memory leaks?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, memory-leaks

I have a class and here is its XAML partial side:

```
<Grid x:Class="KETAB.KStudio.Stage.KPage" Name="Scaller"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:aero="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:KETAB.KStudio.Models;assembly=KETAB.KStudio.Models"
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:KETAB.KStudio.Stage"
      Cursor="None"
    xmlns:Header_Footer="clr-namespace:KETAB.KStudio.Stage.Header_Footer" AllowDrop="True"  Width="{Binding Path=Width}"  Height="{Binding Path=Height}"  >
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/KETAB.KStudio.Stage;component/Resources/StageResources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/KETAB.KStudio.UserControls;component/SharedDictionaryGreen.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
<!--"{Binding ElementName=PagesList, Path=ScaleX}"--> 
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform   ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=PagesList, Path=ScaleX}"
                                         ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=PagesList, Path=ScaleY}"
                        ></ScaleTransform>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>

    <!--Width="{Binding Path=Width}"  Height="{Binding Path=Height}"-->
    <aero:SystemDropShadowChrome Name="ShadowChrome" Opacity="0.75" Margin="0,0,-5,-5"  />  
    <!--Width="{Binding Path=Width}"  Height="{Binding Path=Height}"-->
    <Border  BorderBrush="{StaticResource dark}"  BorderThickness="1.5" Name="PageBorder"   >
        <!--Width="{Binding Path=WidthViewModel , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:Page_ViewModel}}}"  Height="{Binding Path=Height , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:Page_ViewModel}}}"-->

            <Grid  Name="Sizer"   >

            <Canvas Name="Layout"  Background="{StaticResource light}" ClipToBounds="True" Cursor="None"/>

            <Canvas Name="ImportedImageLayer"  Background="Transparent" ClipToBounds="True" Cursor="None"/>

            <p:InkSurface  x:Name="LayerInkSurface"  Cursor="None"  />

            <p:TempSurface  x:Name="TempSurface0" Cursor="None"  />
            <p:TempSurface  x:Name="TempSurface1" Cursor="None"  />



            <p:Surface  x:Name="LayerOnTopTools"  Cursor="None"  >

            </p:Surface>


            <p:Surface  x:Name="DraggingSurface0"  Cursor="None" />
            <p:Surface  x:Name="DraggingSurface1"  Cursor="None" />

            <Header_Footer:HeaderFooterView x:Name="MyHeaderView" VerticalAlignment="Top" PictureVerticalAlignment="Top"  MyVerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Header_Footer:HeaderFooterView x:Name="MyFooterView" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" PictureVerticalAlignment="Bottom" MyVerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

            <Canvas  Name="GridsCanvas"  ClipToBounds="True"  IsHitTestVisible="False">

            </Canvas>

            <p:TopViewLayer  x:Name="PageTopView"  ClipToBounds="True" />


        </Grid>

    </Border>

</Grid>
```

The code behind has a dispose method, which will dispose instances mentioned in the XAML:

```
public void Dispose()
{
LayerInkSurface.Dispose();
LayerOnTopTools.Dispose();
TempSurface0.Dispose();
TempSurface1.Dispose();

DraggingSurface0.Dispose();
DraggingSurface1.Dispose();
}
```

But, when I did memory profiling, I found that the root paths responsible for memory leaks was:

```
DraggingSurface0
DraggingSurface1
LayerOnTopTools
```

Is this because I didn't nullify them? shall do:

```
DraggingSurface0= null;
DraggingSurface1= null;
LayerOnTopTools= null;
```

After disposing them? will this really matter?

Comment: perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502761/disposing-wpf-user-controls ?

Answer (score 0):

Chek out this blog post (perhaps it due to data binding):
http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.se/2010/05/memory-leaks-in-wpf-applications.html