# Visual Studio 2013 WPF UserControl RoutedEvent Name Already Used?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, visual-studio-2013

I have a WPF project in Visual Studio 2013 which contains a custom control I created, containing a custom event. Whenever I drag the control into my `MainWindow.xaml` file, it will display once in the designer. As soon as I compile my application (which succeeds), the designer will display something like this, showing my control is broken:

[image]

In the XAML code (again, only after the first compile), I get this tip:

[image]

However, no matter what I change my event name to (say "EggsAndBaconEvent"), it will always break the designer after the first compile.

Visual Studio will try to help me in this window:

[image]

Here is my code which is related to creating an event:

```
public partial class Settings : UserControl {
    ...

    public static RoutedEvent ExpandEvent;

    public Settings() {
        ...

        ExpandEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Expanded", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Settings));
    }

    ...

    public event RoutedEventHandler Exapnd {
        add { AddHandler(ExpandEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ExpandEvent, value); }
    }

    private void expanderChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ...

        RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(ExpandEvent);
        RaiseEvent(args);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why Visual Studio is complaining? Is it my code or is this some strange anomaly in VS 2013?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more researching, I found that it was Design Mode trying to execute code it couldn't evaluate properly. To prevent Design Mode from doing this, wrap the offending code, like this:

```
if(!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) {
    ... Design Mode won't look at this ...
}
```

So, in my case, if I wrap the event registration, like this:

```
if(!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) {
    ExpandEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Expanded",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(Settings)
    );
}
```

... Design Mode will not break, and the application continues to run as expected.

Here are some cases where I found you may need to include such a preventative:

- Event Registration
- Accessing app.config
- Using C# to update any control properties at initialization time

Comment: In my case this doesn't help. Only explicit unsubscribe from the event helps (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13930385/585819). But for this I need to run and close the application.

Answer (score 0):

That error means exactly what it says:

> There is a `RoutedEvent` named `Expanded` that has already been registered with an `OwnerType` of `Settings`

That means that you have somehow duplicated this line of code:

```
ExpandEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "Expanded",                    /* name */
    RoutingStrategy.Bubble,        /* routingStrategy */ 
    typeof(RoutedEventHandler),    /* handlerType */
    typeof(Settings)               /* ownerType <--- Duplicated */
);
```

You *may* have copied and pasted it into a different control, but forgot to update the `OwnerType` value from `Settings` to the correct class name. If you search for `typeof(Settings)`, you should find it.

Comment: I did a Solution-wide search for `typeof(Settings)` and did not find it anywhere else.

Comment: Then try a Clean and then Build operation. There is no other reason for this error and I have never seen it occur incorrectly.

Comment: So, cleaning works, until the first compile, then it continues to reiterate the same error. That is why I'm so stumped. :)

Comment: Ok, try this: Comment out your `ExpandEvent` declaration and Rebuild the project. The error should disappear. Then uncomment it and Rebuild.

Comment: Commenting out the event entirely causes everything to work well. However, if I just try the declaration, I can't compile, since it says the `ExpandEvent` is not defined... :(

Comment: Well clearly, if something references the event, you'd need to comment that out as well. So after commenting it all out and then uncommenting it, you still get the error? If you do, I'd say that it's time for you to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: No, nothing currently references the event, and I had commented out all of the event declarations and definitions. That worked, until I added all of the definitions back in. Restarting VS wasn't any good, either, as this has been a problem since yesterday.

Comment: Sorry then, I'm all out of suggestions.